# ng-repeat not updating when text pushed to array in scope on ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been bashing my head against a wall trying to figure this out for an embarrassingly long amount of time. I'm trying to update an array in an array that's part of the $scope in AngularJS.

The $scope actually does update, as the console.log shows, but the ng-repeat fails to add the new element. I've tried $scope.$apply, but it says that's already running. What am I missing?

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="event in events">
        <span>The next event is happening on {{event.eventDate}}</span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="attendee in event">{{event.attendees[$index]}}</li>
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="addAttendee($index)">
            <input type="text" ng-model="attendeeText" placeholder="add a new attendee here" />
            <input type="submit" value="add attendee" />
        </form>
        <hr />
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.events = [
            {eventDate:'25/09/2013',attendees:['Pinky','The Brian']},
            {eventDate:'30/10/2013',attendees:['Robocop','The Terminator']}
        ];

        $scope.addAttendee = function(index) {
            $scope.events[index].attendees.push(this.attendeeText);
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.events[index]));
            this.attendeeText = '';
        };
    };
</script>
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if it's a blindingly obvious error on my part!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not asking it to display the added items. Change this line

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="attendee in event">{{event.attendees[$index]}}</li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="attendee in event.attendees">{{attendee}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I never would have thought to do that!

Answer (score 0):

please try this

HTML

```
    <div  ng-app  ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="event in events">
    <span>The next event is happening on {{event.eventDate}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="attendee in event.attendees">{{attendee}}</li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="addAttendee($index)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="attendeeText" placeholder="add a new attendee here" />
        <input type="submit" value="add attendee" />
    </form>
    <hr />
</div>


       </div>
```

JS

```
    function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.events = [
        {eventDate:'25/09/2013',attendees:['Pinky','The Brian']},
        {eventDate:'30/10/2013',attendees:['Robocop','The Terminator']}
    ];

    $scope.addAttendee = function(index) {
        $scope.events[index].attendees.push(this.attendeeText);
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.events[index]));
        this.attendeeText = '';
    };
};
```

you can refer below fiddle also

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1457/